# Fileinfo - c# Vs2008

Tags: c#

Can I use FileInfo as such:

```
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"\\mymachine\downloads\;\\yourmachine\Log\" +  "11.txt");
StreamWriter sw = fileInfo.CreateText();
sw.WriteLine("write some data");
sw.Close();
```

My lead thinks it can be used as such but I get an exception when I run that code..

Exception:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Could not find a part of the path
```

He thinks he can do a fake load balance and/or depending on which share is available the code will place an order file to be processed. I do not agree with his thinking but he my boss and i gotta do his biding..

Comment: What are you trying to acheive with that code, especially with the path `@"\\mymachine\downloads\;\\yourmachine\Log\"`?

Comment: added extra code and exception..

Comment: i agree with you not agreeing :-)

Answer (score 3):

The FileInfo constructor takes the path to a single file; what you're passing it is not a valid file name, so I'd expect an `ArgumentException`. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Based on your additional comments: no, FileInfo() doesn't work that way. You're gonna have to check each possible share separately to see which are available and write your log file there.

Answer (score 0):

FileInfo just doesn't work like that. You're going to have to use something like File.Exists to see which file is available and then write code to write to one share or the other.